# JBoss Netty framework HTTP website

Tags: netty

Hello everybody I'm trying to make my own web site with framework JBoss Netty, server starts OK. But how I can load my website to server?
For example i all ready have index.html, what I must do to see this page on server ?

Comment: Take a look at webbit on github they are doing this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should head over to the [examples](http://www.jboss.org/netty/documentation.html) page and look at both the [HTTP (Snoop)](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/http/snoop/package-summary.html) and the [HTTP (File Server)](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/http/file/package-summary.html) samples.

The second one will actually server static pages, which is what you're after if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: Thank you, ill check examples again